# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 31

Tags: java

```
//read each character in the string st[] array and compare it with second array st1[].

for(int i=0;i<=7;i++){   
    for(int j=0;j<=31;j++){
        if(st[i].charAt(j)!= st1[i].charAt(j))
         x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: i think the exception cannot be more clear, there is no 32nd character in one of your strings

Answer (score 2):

seems that `charAt(j)` where `j = 31` do not exists.

try to change this line

```
for(int j=0;j<=31;j++)
```

into

```
for( int j = 0; j < st[i].length() && j < st1[i].length(); j++)
```

Comment: that should be a min of the length of the two strings

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a string with a length of `31` (or less), yet you're attempting to get the 32nd character with the index `j` being `31`.

Try

```
for(int j = 0; j < 31; j++)
```

or even

```
for(int j = 0; j < st[i].length(); j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the array lengths and String lengths in your for loops to avoid going past the boundaries:

```
for(int i=0; i < st.length && i < st1.length; i++) {   
    for(int j=0;j< st[i].length() && j < st1[i].length(); j++){
        if(st[i].charAt(j)!= st1[i].charAt(j))
            x++;
    }
}
```